# POST request with android on https page with htaccess

Tags: android, post, ssl

I've been looking quite everywhere and the infos I have found didn't worked with my case.
Could someone help me please with this :
I need to send a POST request to a specific url on a server with an Android application.
The target page is using https encryption and is protected by an htaccess.
Last things : the server listen on a random port like 14000 and in the certificate the hostname is different from the hostname's url.
I know that is quite challenging but nothing i've tried is working.
Curently i try this :

```
private void process() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            String httpsURL = "https://login:password@z-cloud.z-wave.me/ZWaveAPI/Data/0";
            HttpResponse httpResponse;
            HttpPost httpQuery = new HttpPost(httpsURL);
            CustomHttpClient myClient = new CustomHttpClient(myContext);
            Log.v("exec", "ready...");
            try {
                httpResponse = myClient.execute(httpQuery);
                if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    Log.v("exec", "it works ?");
                }
                Log.v("exec", httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()+"");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.d("httpError", ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

and the CustomHttpClient class :

```
public class CustomHttpClient extends DefaultHttpClient {

private static Context appContext = null;
private static Scheme httpsScheme = null;
private static Scheme httpScheme = null;
private static String TAG = "MyHttpClient";

public CustomHttpClient(Context myContext) {

    appContext = myContext;

    if (httpScheme == null || httpsScheme == null) {
        httpScheme = new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80);
        httpsScheme = new Scheme("https", mySSLSocketFactory(), 14000);
    }

    getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry().register(httpScheme);
    getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry().register(httpsScheme);

}

@SuppressWarnings("finally")
private SSLSocketFactory mySSLSocketFactory() {
    SSLSocketFactory ret = null;
    try {
        final KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");

        final InputStream inputStream = appContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.certs);

        ks.load(inputStream, appContext.getString(R.string.store_pass).toCharArray());
        inputStream.close();
        ret = new SSLSocketFactory(ks);
        ret.setHostnameVerifier(myhostnameVerifier);
    } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, ex.getMessage());
    } catch (KeyStoreException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, ex.getMessage());
    } catch (KeyManagementException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, ex.getMessage());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, ex.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, ex.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        return ret;
    }
}

X509HostnameVerifier myhostnameVerifier = new X509HostnameVerifier() {

    @Override
    public void verify(String arg0, SSLSocket arg1) throws IOException {
        Log.v("X509", "verified "+arg0);
        if("z-cloud.z-wave.me" != arg0)
        {
            //throw new SSLException("Mismatching hostname");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void verify(String arg0, X509Certificate arg1)
            throws SSLException {
        Log.v("X509", "called 2");
    }

    @Override
    public void verify(String arg0, String[] arg1, String[] arg2)
            throws SSLException {
        Log.v("X509", "called 3");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean verify(String host, SSLSession session) {
        Log.v("X509", "called 4");
        return false;
    }
};
}
```

I don't know why but i'm getting an error 401 but m'y login and password are good.
I'm not really sure that the certificate i use is correct, but do i really need it ?
Please help me, i'm getting really tired trying to send a simple post request...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is indeed to use a custom TrustStore containing the server's certificate. It's probably not necessary to validate the hostname - the certificate should be all that's needed.

Rather than trying to debug your code, I'll point you to a blog posting that I did a while back that has a full working example of how to do this. Take a look at http://blog.chariotsolutions.com/2013/01/https-with-client-certificates-on.html

Edit - the example shows how to use a client certificate, which you don't need - just ignore that part.

Comment: Hi ! thank for your help ! I managed to connect to the server with your post, but i had to add something i forgot : the authentication header with the couple login/password in base64 encryption. Thank for your reply !